# Get order id from purchased downlodable product id

Tags: increment-id, download-link

How can I get order id from purchased downlodable product ?

Please check my below code :

```
$purchased = Mage::getResourceModel('downloadable/link_purchased_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id)
        ->addOrder('created_at', 'desc');

$purchasedItems = Mage::getResourceModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('purchased_id', array('in' => $purchasedIds))
        ->addFieldToFilter('status',
            array(
                'nin' => array(
                    Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PENDING_PAYMENT,
                    Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PAYMENT_REVIEW
                )
            )
        )
        ->setOrder('item_id', 'desc');


foreach ($items as $item)
{ 
    -- Here I wand to get Order id of each items ---
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution because it involves having a load in a loop, but it's better than nothing.

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{ 
    $orderItemId = $item->getOrderItemId();
    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($orderItemId);
    $orderId = $orderItem->getOrderId();//this is what you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think simple query easily works for you

```
    $readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $sfoi = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('sales_flat_order_item');
    foreach ($items as $item)
    { 
        $itemId=$item->getId();
        $query="SELECT order_id FROM $sfoi WHERE item_id=$itemId";
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        $orderId=$results[0]['order_id'];    
    }
```